# Cannot open source file "stdio.h" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm new to C and this is my first project using visual studio. I have #include <stdio.h> in the first line of the code but there is an error "cannot open source file "stdio.h" C/C++ (1696)". I have installed the Microsoft C/C++ extension. I am happy to clarify anything. Thank you!

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Me, I would be inclined to complain to the vendor.  This is the logical equivalent of sitting down in your new car and discovering that there's no steering wheel.  A C compiler that cannot compile a C program beginning with `#include <stdio.h>` has just failed just one of the very first and most basic requirements of being a C compiler.

Comment: There is a huge difference between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. The former is an expensive propriatery IDE including a compiler, the latter is just an editor.

Answer (score 2):

### Note:

Be aware that `VSCode` is simply an [editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_what-is-the-difference-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio-ide). With some extensions installed, it may help you code "faster & easier".

[image: The C/C++ extension that I use]

---

### Solution:

But in order for you to **compile the code** it is less beginner friendly than IDEs like [CodeBlocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/).

The way I do it is by going to :

- Terminal **>** New terminal
- `cd "the_directory_in_which_the_file.c_exists"` (*don't forget the double quotes*)
- `gcc "file.c"`
- `./a.out` (`./a.exe` on Windows)

[image: Example: Hello Stackoverflow !]

---

### Just in case:

- if `gcc` (the compiler in this case) is not installed, then you can quickly do so by following [this article](https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j)'s steps if you use Windows, or [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-linux/) if you are on Linux.

Comment: +1, with the _caveat_ that some terminals are more user-friendly then others in this regard. This explains how to [run files which are developed in VS Code editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp).